# Share data from text file between multiple forms

Tags: c#, winforms, file

I have a  problem with a C# Win Forms application that I am making.
In the Program,  I am using a  *.txt* file to store my data -it's like a small database -.
So, I want to open the file once and close it also once when I terminate the program.
My Problem is: I don't  know how to pass the data in the *.txt*  files to all of the forms in the program.
Note: I want to open the *.txt* files in *Form1*  and pass the data to all other forms < *Form n* >.

Comment: You can make a static handle to the file and call it from everywehere you want. It's not the cleanest approach. You should show some examples of your code.

Comment: See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: You can also pass the data into the constructor of the whatever new form you are initialising. Like @farbiondriven's suggestion, not the cleanest but will work

Answer (score 0):

A good idea would be to create a static class that will manage the data in the file, thus you will be able to use it everywhere.

The code would be something like this:

```
public static FileManager
{

    // You can change this to a Dictionary or whatefver you need
    public static readonly List<string> Data { get; }


    // Static constructor, will be called once
    // Here you will populate your data
    static FileManager()
    {
        Data = new List<string>();
        // Read from file and add data to Data, assuming the data is lines
    }

}
```

And then in any form or class, just use the `FileManager.Data` property :)

Comment: https://ideone.com/cnSEs3 this is my code i don't know why but it doesn't work did i do something wrong? @Haitam

Comment: You forgot to add "using System.Collections.Generic;"

Comment: It's Included .

Comment: Your ideone says otherwise, is the bug not this?

Comment: i only showed you the template of the function  the  program  is way  bigger

Comment: I will need more informations then, the code provided doesn't seem to have any issues. Whats the exact error?

Comment: You might want to create a FileManager.cs file and put the static file there.

Comment: Still Doesn't Work